# Looping LiveStream on Youtube using Amazon Services

Tags: youtube, aws-media-live

I'm trying to stream a long video (6 hours) to Youtube using amazon services 24/7.
I followed this guide https://aws.amazon.com/ru/blogs/publicsector/live-streaming-facebook-youtube-aws-elemental-medialive/ and it seems that everything worked. But there is one problem. When the broadcast ends, viewers in YouTube see a black screen. What can I do to start the video from the beginning, and make all this works in a cycle in 24/7 mode.

When i'm trying to configure my Amazon LiveMedia Channel to make my input video looped, i don't see the desired option.

[image]

What can i do to make my LiveStream looped?

Answer (score 1):

I found: Edit the channel >> Click on the required Input under 'Input attachments' >> Under 'General input settings' please update the value of 'Source End Behavior' to 'LOOP'